# Why does VBA consider -1 < 3 < 2 to be True?

Tags: vba, if-statement

I have an If statement that checks whether a value is between two integers. A simple check, which I thought I could tackle through `-1 < x < 2` where x contains any integer.

However, when `x = 3` for example, VBA considers the statement to be true, even though this clearly is not the case.

I know I can simply avoid this issue by using `If -1 < x And x < 2 Then` instead, but I'd like to know why the former statement doesn't produce the expected output. I tried looking online for an answer, but failed to find any.

Comment: Don't know VBA specifically, but in most programming languages operators are processed one at a time. `-1 < x < 2` --> `(-1 < x ) < 2` --> `true < 2` --> `1 < 2` --> `true` (boolean true is usually coerced to 1 in comparisons with numbers.)

Comment: @Guy Incognito: You are right, except for `True`, this is not `1` but `-1`. That's true in most programming languages because the binary representation of -1 has all bits set to 1.

Comment: Thanks @GuyIncognito. I tried to check for this with `-1 < 2 < 0`, which should by your logic resolve to `(-1 < 2) < 0` --> `true < 0` = `1 < 0` --> `False`. However, `true` was returned. Either VBA treats `True < x` to be true always, or your explanation is not true for VBA

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks Thomas, I love solid 0s. If only my professors would think the same..

Comment: @FunThomas Fair enough, but I'd consider VBA an exception here, all major languages coerce true to 1 (C, C++, Java, Javascript, Python, ...) I've never heard or seen true converted to -1.

Comment: @GuyIncognito: vb.net defines True as ~0 too. PASCAL is another instance too.

Comment: I learned programming some 35 years ago with (Turbo-) Pascal where True was -1. Have to admit that I thought it's the same for C, but a quick Google showed that I was wrong. Anyhow, doing numeric calculations with a boolean is a horrible thing. When you are in the situation that you need to know the value of a boolean, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @FunThomas: Yes note that C++ has deprecated `b++` for a `bool` type `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, `-1 < 3 < 2` is evaluated as `(-1 < 3) < 2`

`(-1 < 3)` is `True`.

The important thing to note that in VBA, `True` is equal to -1.

`-1 < 2` is `True`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I previously commented on how `-1 < 2 < 0` results in `True` thinking `True = 1`, but since `True = -1` I tested `-6 < -5 < - 4` which equals `False`, as to be expected.